# Intellij java.lang.NoSuchFieldError on startup after update

Tags: java, intellij-idea, startup, intellij-plugin, intellij-14

I just updated IntelliJ and have gotten the following message on startup:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: mimicJarUrlConnection
    at com.intellij.util.lang.ZipResourceFile$ZipFileResource.<init>(ZipResourceFile.java:150)
    at com.intellij.util.lang.ZipResourceFile.getResource(ZipResourceFile.java:136)
    at com.intellij.util.lang.JarLoader.getResource(JarLoader.java:129)
    at com.intellij.util.lang.ClassPath.findResource(ClassPath.java:240)
    at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.doFindResource(UrlClassLoader.java:315)
    at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(UrlClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getResourceAsStream(Class.java:2650)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.ApplicationNamesInfo.loadData(ApplicationNamesInfo.java:28)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.ApplicationNamesInfo.initAndGetRawData(ApplicationNamesInfo.java:45)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationInfoImpl.getShadowInstance(ApplicationInfoImpl.java:478)
    at com.intellij.idea.SplashManager.show(SplashManager.java:57)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lambda$scheduleInitUi$7(StartupUtil.java:385)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:776)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)

-----
!bootstrap.error.message.jre.details!11.0.10+9-b1341.35 x86_64 (JetBrains s.r.o.)
/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home!
```

I think I may need to delete a plugin or two but am not sure how to figure out which one. Thoughts?

Comment: Try reindex & restart option

Comment: Does the reinstall from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html help? See also https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007568559.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into a similar error (same Exception, different field: SECRETS). My SonarLint and AsciiDoc Plugins were outdated, apparently causing the Exception. Updating the Plugins helped.